# What determines strength of a phase transition?

Tags: field-theory, phase-transition

Consider a phase transition involving a scalar field $\phi$. After including temperature corrections to a typical Mexican hat potential, one obtains,

$$ V(\phi, T) = D ( T^2 - T_0^2) \phi^2 - ET\phi^3 + \lambda(T) \phi^4.$$

The critical temperature is defined as the temperature at which the two minima are degenerate. The strength of phase transition is characterised by the parameter

$$ \frac{\phi_c}{T_c}$$

where $T_c$ is the critical temperature and $\phi_c$ is the vev of the field at $T_c$. You will often find the following characterisation:

$$ \frac{\phi_c}{T_c} \geq 1 \quad \rightarrow \text{First Order} $$

$$ \frac{\phi_c}{T_c} >> 1 \quad \rightarrow \text{Strong First Order} $$

My question is, Why is $\frac{\phi_c}{T_c}$ the measure of strength of the phase transition?

Edit: 
For example, take the Reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05853.pdf (Section: Introduction, Parah. # 2)

Comment: Can you cite the relevant reference?

Comment: @SRS, I have added a reference. Thanks for pointing out!